# How to use dataset in sql command

Tags: sql, vb.net, dataset

Please see below code for reference.

I am getting this error on my code below and I already know why, I just don't know how am I going to JOIN the dataset inside SQL.

***Error1   Operator '+' is not defined for types 'String' and 'System.Data.DataTable'.***

```
 Dim sql3 As String = "select DISTINCT A.CustomerNum, A.CustomerName, A.lngAmkorID AS AmkorID, A.lngAmkorSubID AS SubID, A.strLineCode AS LineCode, A.Device, A.WaferRunNum, A.PkgLd, A.strPO AS PO, A.strWIPLotNumber as WIPLotNo, A.strWIPLotDoubleCheckCode AS WIPDCC, " & _
                          "J.strOperatorName AS CurrOper, J.strRawDateCode AS eMES_DC, J.strRawTraceCode AS eMES_TC, " & _
                          "K.ReferenceStnName, " & _
                          "D.CMMFDT AS MfgDate, " & _
                          "C.DateCode AS Marked_DC, 'HardcodedDC' = CASE WHEN C.HardCoded <> 0 THEN 'Hardcoded'  ELSE '' END," & _
                       "C.TraceCode as encicledT, 'HardcodedT' = CASE WHEN C.bolTCHardcoded <> 0 THEN 'Hardcoded'  ELSE '' END," & _
                       "C.SCode as encicledU, 'HardcodedU' = CASE WHEN C.bolSCHardcoded <> 0 THEN 'Hardcoded'  ELSE '' END," & _
                       "C.SeqCode as encicledQ, 'HardcodedQ' = CASE WHEN C.bolQCHardcoded <> 0 THEN 'Hardcoded'  ELSE '' END," & _
                          "'Status' = CASE" & _
              "WHEN B.Status = 0 THEN 'NEW LOT'" & _
              "WHEN B.Status = 1 THEN 'INCOMPLETE MID'" & _
              "WHEN B.Status = 2 THEN 'COMPLETE MID'" & _
              "WHEN B.Status = 3 THEN 'DC PROCESSED'" & _
              "WHEN B.Status = 5 THEN 'MARKED'" & _
                 "END," & _
                          "'HOLD' = CASE WHEN B.Hold <> 0 THEN 'ON HOLD'  ELSE '' END," & _
                       "D.CMMKDT AS MarkDate, H.strILNNo AS MESA_ILN, " & _
                       "J.strStation AS Station, J.strStatus_01 AS Status1, J.strStatus_02 AS Status2, " & _
                       "'UnitQty' = CASE" & _
              "WHEN J.lngShippingOutTotalGoodQuantity <> 0 THEN J.lngShippingOutTotalGoodQuantity" & _
              "WHEN J.lngShippingGoodEOH <> 0 THEN J.lngShippingGoodEOH" & _
              "WHEN I.lngDieQuantity <> 0 THEN I.lngDieQuantity" & _
              "WHEN J.lngCurrentDieGoodEOH <> 0 THEN J.lngCurrentDieGoodEOH" & _
              "ELSE 0" & _
                          "End" & _
                          "from tblMIDCustomerLot A" & _
                          "INNER JOIN tblMIDExt B on A.lngAmkorID = B.lngAmkorID AND A.lngAmkorSubID = B.lngAmkorSubID and A.strWIPLotNumber = B.strWIPLotNumber COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS" & _
                          "INNER JOIN tblText C on A.lngAmkorID = C.lngAmkorID AND A.lngAmkorSubID = C.lngAmkorSubID and A.strWIPLotNumber = C.strWIPLotNumber COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS" & _
                          "LEFT JOIN " + ***ds.Tables("AMDSLot")*** + " D ON A.lngAmkorID = D.CMAMKID" & _
           "AND A.lngAmkorSubID = D.CMSUBID" & _
           "AND A.strWIPLotNumber = D.CMCLTN COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS" & _
           "AND CAST(C.ReferenceStn AS INT)= D.CMREFS " & _
                          "LEFT JOIN dbDownload.MesLib.tblCrossRefILNAmkorID H ON A.lngAmkorID = H.lngWipAmkorId AND A.lngAmkorSubID = H.intWipSubId" & _
                          "LEFT JOIN dbDownload.MesLib.tblSplitAndCombineChangeLog I ON A.lngAmkorID = I.lngToAmkorID AND A.lngAmkorSubID = I.lngToAmkorSubID AND I.strType = 'COMBINE'" & _
                          "INNER JOIN " + ***ds.Tables("Table1")*** + " J ON A.lngAmkorID = J.lngAmkorID AND A.lngAmkorSubID = J.lngAmkorSubID" & _
                          "LEFT JOIN P1Common.dbo.tblReferenceStation K ON A.CustomerNum = K.CustomerCode AND A.CustomerName = K.CustomerName and C.ReferenceStn = K.ReferenceStn" & _
                          "where (C.DateCode <> '' or C.TraceCode <> '' or C.SCode <> '' or C.SeqCode <> '')" & _
                       "AND C.ReferenceStn <> '*FIRST'" & _
                          "order by A.strWIPLotNumber, A.strWIPLotDoubleCheckCode"

        Dim dataadapter3 As New SqlDataAdapter(sql3, connection)
```

Thanks in Advance! :)

Comment: Welcome to SO.  In the future, please highlight your code and press Ctrl-K to format it so others can read it. :)

Comment: I would recommend using a stored procedure for this - that's an awful lot of SQL and having it broken across multiple lines and enclosed is quotes increasing the complexity, IMO.

Comment: Where does the data for dataset comes from? Can u combine the data there? If not - you may have to run your query separately and do a join later perhaps via LINQ

Comment: you are specifying the table name indirectly (or trying), why not do so directly?  instead of `"LEFT JOIN " + ds.Tables("AMDSLot")"` use `"LEFT JOIN AMDSLot"` your later INNER JOIN one has a typo

Comment: Use SQL syntax instead of using `ds.Tables`.

Comment: Are you trying to query a database or a DataSet?

Comment: Perhaps ds.Tables("AMDSLot").Name   You should be using & instead of + in VB. ds.Tables("AMDSLot") doesn't return a String but a DataTable.